# Binance API, корректные параметры getAggTrades

Tags: java

```
List<AggTrade> aggTrades = client.getAggTrades("NEOETH", String.valueOf(aggTrades1.get(0).getAggregatedTradeId()-1000), 10, System.currentTimeMillis() - 3000, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Добрый день!
Хочется получить историю сделок по паре за последние 3 секунды.
Все время при любых комбинациях возникает ошибка:
Exception in thread "main" com.binance.api.client.exception.BinanceApiException: Combination of optional parameters invalid.

Непонятно как корректно получить tradeId и согласованные с ними времянки?

Comment: Спасибо, я это пропустил, также вместо tradeId можно тоже передать null, достаточно только времени!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<AggTrade> aggTrades = client.getAggTrades("NEOETH", null, null, System.currentTimeMillis() - 60000, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Для работы достаточно передавать только время.
При этом, время сервера и биржи должно быть синхронизовано.